# Tab a text block in vim with mswin

Tags: vim

I am using vim with mswin (http://ftp.nluug.nl/vim/runtime/mswin.vim) so that I can use control-C,X,V,Z,Y,A,S in common manner.

However, I want to add tabs (`\t`) to each line of a selected block of text. I can do it with following vim function code:

```
function Tabs ()  
  :'<,'>s/^/\t/g
  :noh              " to remove highlighting
endfunction
```

The usage is as follows:

```
Press ESC > ctrl-Q > select block > :call Tabs()
```

It works but I have to do a lot of steps. Even "`:Tabs()`" does not work. Can I bind this to `Tab` key or any other key for easier use?

Comment: Why not simply `>>`?

Comment: @romainl : Only one `>` works. Why did you write `>>`?

Comment: Early mornings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both. It would be better to make the function range-aware (`:help :function`, `:help func-range`, `:help :execute`). Also, you do not need colons in a Vimscript file; and replacing the start of a line cannot be done multiple times per line, so `/g` modifier is useless. I also use `:function!` instead of `:function`, to ensure that if you reload the file where it is defined no error is raised.

```
function! Tabs() range
  exec a:firstline.",".a:lastline."s/^/\t"
  noh
endfunction
```

As you said, functions are called using `call Tabs()` syntax (`:help :call`). `:Tabs` would be a *command*, and you can make a new command in the following way. (`:help :command`, `:help commmand-range`, `:help line1`, `:help line2`).

```
command! -range Tabs <line1>,<line2>call Tabs()
```

You can also make it into a keyboard mapping. (`:help :vnoremap`).

```
vnoremap <Tab> :call Tabs()<CR>
```

We rely here on the fact that pressing `:` in visual mode will not only put you in command mode, but also insert `'<,'>` range into the command line (so that the binding actually calls `:'<,'>call Tabs()`). (`:help cmdline-ranges`, `:help '<`, `:help '>`)

**However, that said,** if you just want to add an indent to a block, just press `>` in visual mode (`:help >`). If your file is meant to be tab-indented (i.e. your options are `set noexpandtab tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8` or any other setting where tabstop is equal to shiftwidth), it will insert the tab at the start of the line(s). (`:help :set`, `:help 'expandtab'`, `:help 'tabstop'`, `:help 'shiftwidth'`) If your options are `set expandtab` (signifying you wish to indent using spaces, not tabs), then `>` will indent by the number of spaces equal to shiftwidth.

As usual, you can double the command to make it indent the current line (`>>`), or apply a text object (e.g. `>ap` to indent a paragraph), etc. There is an opposite binding, `<`, that outdents (again, according to the relevant options).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I can use `>` only once. For adding another tab to same block, I have to again press `control-Q, select block and press >`. Is it possible that once started, I can repeated press > and < keys to get correct tabbing of block of text (as I can do in Geany text editor using Tab and Shift-Tab keys)?

Comment: Here's not one, but three ways: a) In visual mode, `3>` will indent three times (`:help v_<`) b) After visual mode `>`, you can reapply indent using `.` (`:help .`) c) You can reselect the last visual selection for further manipulation using `gv` (`:help gv`). I generally use b) if I don't know the exact count - if I need to apply somewhere around four indents, I'll select a block, then `>...`. If I indent too much, I can go back using `u` (`:help undo`).

Comment: I also find `>....` for tabbing and `u` for undoing best. Can these movement be done using Tab and Shift-Tab?

Comment: You _could_ bind some logic to `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>`, but it would not be quite straightforward. I strongly advise you to adapt to Vim, rather than try to adapt Vim to you. Vim is quite opinionated, and if you want to use a Windows-style editor, you'll be better served by using a real one (like Notepad++) rather than trying to beat a square peg into a round hole. Even visual mode is something that new Vimmers overuse, as text objects usually provide a more intuitive and more powerful way of manipulation, which is not obvious if you stick to "safe" way you're used to.